# update timestamp just on insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Last night, I created a `column` called `time` in my `table`, the type is `TIMESTAMP` and default is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and attribute is `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (all set by default) and it will add timestamp when a new data is inserted, it works fine, and it shows all data (items) on my front page ORDER by this `timestamp` but this morning I noticed that one of my item's timestamp updated automatically! only `hour` changed. Now this problem repeated on another item.

Then I figured out that when I open the link to an item (another page that shows all the data belonging to the item), the timestamp will update. In this page I just fetch data from `db`

```
print_r($ads);
```

And the query is simple `SELECT FROM TABLE`, I'm wondering why this happen?

*I know I should post code here, but this is `mysql` thing and there is no related code. If need, please let me know, then update my post.*

**Edit:** i forget something, when this page open, it increase counter:

```
$sql = "UPDATE ads SET view = view + 1 WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: `ON UPDATE` will also change the time when the record is udpated, not just when it is inserted. This may be your problem, but then again we don't have a lot of info to work with so it's hard to be sure

Comment: @WilliamPerron I updated my question, so what should i do? i just want insert timestamp when new data inserted

Comment: Is this work? `SET timestamp = timestamp` OR `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: i'm not sure but i would try  `UPDATE ads SET view = view + 1,  timestamp = timestamp WHERE id = $id`

Comment: @splash58 yes, `timestamp = timestamp` works.

Comment: @martian I's very well

Answer (score 1):

`... i just want insert timestamp when new data inserted ...`

Change the `on update` trigger to `before insert on`. This should limit the time field change action to only when the row is inserted.

Comment: There is no such option, it just `BINARY` and `UNSIGNED` and `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` and `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @martian, check the mysql [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) reference